# Was Richard Feynman really awarded a patent for a nuclear Airplane and Rocket?

Tags: biographical-details, nuclear-physics, world-war-2, physicists, feynman

I've been re-reading "Surely you're Joking Mr. Feynman", and at one point he talks about how at Los Alamos they were asked to write down any idea, no matter how obvious involving nuclear technology, and the government would patent it.  Feynman thinks this is ridiculous, and says he'll be talking to them all day with endless ideas of using a nuclear reactor to power things like a submarine, and airplane, a rocket, etc.

He winds up getting the patent for the airplane and the rocket, but someone already got the patent for the nuclear submarine.

While reading this, it suddenly occurred to me that patent searches are incredibly easy these days, and available on Google.  But try as I might I couldn't find any patent issued to Richard Feynman at all.  There were certainly other patents issued to the other nuclear scientists, but none to Feynman.

Now, Feynman also tells a story about how after the war, someone had called him up (Long Distance from all the way from California!) and wanted him to be the director of a laboratory that was going to develop a nuclear powered airplane, because his name was on the patent.

I can guess at a few different possibilities.

1. Feynman is mistaken about this, and there weren't any patents, it was something else entirely or he made the whole story up.
2. The patent(s) was applied for, but never issued because the examiner thought it was too obvious, or there was some other problem with the application.  The story about someone calling him and offering him to be a director arose because they saw the patent application, not the issued patent.
3. The patent(s) was granted, but either can't be found for some reason under Feynman's name (miss-spelling, etc)

Possibility one seems unlikely, especially because of the LD call story.  I tried investigating possibility two, but patent applications only appear to be searchable online since 2001.

Comment: Interesting.  Some defense patents are classified, so I guess it's not impossible Feynman's would be in that category.  But I doubt it since 1) Classified patents are pretty rare, and Feynmans airplane work by his own admission was both pretty obvious and not very detailed and 2) I don't think there are any patents still classified from as far back as the 40's.

Comment: In an [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rc9gwPB78lk) in which he talks about this patent business, Feynman says "I think I got something like three patents, I don't know what they are anymore; three patents have my name on it".

Comment: @njuffa I saw that interview.  Unfortunately there's no patents issued to a Richard Feynman.  His son, Carl, yes.  So that's why I suspect they were applied for, but never issued because patents must be "non-obvious to someone in the art".  What I don't know is if, at the time, patents that were applied for but not examined could be examined by the public.

Comment: Yea, I couldnt find any source for the patents that didn't cite RF himself.  I did find a citation to a private communication with RF on the bib. of an academic history of atomic aircraft though, which makes me think the story isn't a total fabrication, and RF did do some brief post-war work on atomic aircraft, and that provided the basis of the story about being owed one dollar for the idea.  Presumably he changed whatever the actual complicated  bureaucratic issue was to a patent assignment to simplify the anecdote, or misunderstood/misremembered the issue himself.

Comment: Citation mentioned above can be found on page 10 of the below pdf:  https://media.defense.gov/2014/Oct/14/2001329848/-1/-1/0/AFD-141014-032.pdf

Comment: @simplicio Thanks for that find.  My guess is the citation was more about the first instance of someone thinking about nuclear powered aircraft, which was (officially at least) Feynman.

Comment: Spinoff question: did anyone get a patent on the Project Orion rocket?

Comment: "I don't think there are any patents still classified from as far back as the 40's" This is not true. I have obtained a list of all Manhattan Project patents, and some remain classified. As we speak, I'm trying to have the redactions lifted to see who the inventors were. Just today, I was asked to write a "Letter to the Editor to the American Journal of Physics. It will discuss that long list of patents, how they were obtained, and my efforts to have the redactions removed. -- Bill Streifer bill.streifer@gmail.com

Comment: The Manhattan Project patented everything. Until a patent was published, it remained between the inventor and the US Patent Office. Once it was published, it became unclassified and anyone could view the patent details. And those details were very detailed. Regarding how a patent for an aircraft engine could possibly be classified, they ALL were. We're talking about a nuclear engine. Over the years, there have been many nuclear engine patents, they weren't as "obvious" as "you bolt it to a rocket." Nuclear engines have many parts and each part was classified for many years after the Manhattan

Comment: The question is specifically about Feynman's story of getting a patent for an obvious idea, and how ridiculous it all was.  There was no detail, and no design.  The story is Feynman giving a 1 minute description of hooking a nuclear reactor to generate steam, hook that up to a turbine, hook that up to a propeller.  Nuclear airplane.  Same thing with a submarine.  Someone else already got the submarine patent, but he got the nuclear airplane.  I have no idea about other non-obvious ideas.  This question is about an obvious one.

Comment: I personally think Feynman applied for patents but none were issued, otherwise they’d appear in Google Patents. I also think it unlikely that Feynman’s patents remain classified. Someone asked to see a list of all patents related to the Manhattan Project. I obtained such a list through FOIA with the Department of Energy in 2017. That list has since been posted to the Wilson Center’s website, including the classified ones. If you want to see that list of patents, simply Google my name, Wilson Center, Manhattan Project. etc. and the list will bubble to the top. Let me know what you think.

Comment: This patent suggests how a nuclear reactor might be used to propel an aircraft or rocket: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/a8/98/52/952d256cfde735/US2917443.pdf If it's not classified, why would Richard Feynman's supposed patents be?

Comment: By the way, I'm "this close" to locating Richard Feynman's "lost" patents. But it might take several months or more. Once I do, I'm going to write an article about it, perhaps for the American Intelligence Journal where I've been published often. I'll also write an "ANSWER" here,

Comment: @BillStreifer Hello, did you ever get around finding out if Feynman was the inventor?